# Are there any good playable violin tabulatures for Paganini caprices, Bach and Vivaldi music?

Tags: violin, tablature

Are there any violin tabulatures for Paganini caprices, Bach and Vivaldi music? Or that is stupid to write tabs for a fretless instrument?

Comment: I was surprised to find out that tablature for violin exists (and for different positions as well!)  https://bluegrassdaddy.com/hand-and-finger-positions/  But in the end, it would actually make is harder to understand what is going on in such complex music as you cited.  Better to bite the bullet and learn to read sheet music (where fingering and string is often notated as well).

Answer (score 3):

Particularly for Paganini, a lot of stuff is played in higher positions where "frets" are very close to one another.  Quite a bit of the aiming on fretless instruments relies to some degree on reflexive correction of auditory feedback.  That means that it is comparatively more important to have an idea how things are supposed to sound and fit into the harmony than which "fret" they are on.

Stuff written in violin clef tends to be quite more transparent regarding its harmonic and melodic composition than stuff written in a variety of tablature.  So there is a reason for a dearth of literature.

Surprisingly, there *are* actually lute pieces by Paganini (and Bach anyway, but then Bach was more of a multiinstrumentalist): for those, of course tablature makes some sense and the lute, like the guitar, also has larger distances on the fretboard.  The Paganini lute pieces tend to be quite less of vortuosity showoff pieces than the violin ones, too.  That helps in making tablature work reasonably for them.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it can't be the best way to portray music to be played. How would it be done? You could put an overlay with 'fret wires' marked, but it's just as much or little trouble to learn to read the music - of which there is a shedload !